# How to provide a fallback static file for angular-translate?

Tags: angularjs, localization, translate, angular-translate

I'm using translateUrlLoader to bring the resource file from the server. In case this fails, i want to use a local file. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a hack to resolve this. This is the code that I used to do:

```
$translateProvider.translations('default', ResourceConstants.EnglishLabels).fallbackLanguage('default');
```

So basically what this did was take a JSON and use it for populating the translation table in case selected language is 'default'. And then I provide 'default' as the fallback language (name is irrelevant). This is then used in case your get request (ajax)

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('requestPath')
```

fails.